# iOS: Strip <img...> from NSString (a html string)

Tags: html, objective-c, ios, image

So I have an `NSString` which is basically an `html` string with all the usual `html` elements. The specific thing I would like to do is **to just strip it from all the `img` tags.**
The `img` tags may or may not have max-width, style or other attributes so I do not know their length up front. They always end with `/>`

How could I do this?

**EDIT:** Based on `nicolasthenoz`'s answer, I came up with a solution that requires less code:

```
NSString *HTMLTagss = @"<img[^>]*>"; //regex to remove img tag
NSString *stringWithoutImage = [htmlString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfRegex:HTMLTagss withString:@""];
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use the `NSString` method `stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString` with the `NSRegularExpressionSearch` option:

```
NSString *result = [html stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"<img[^>]*>" withString:@"" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch | NSRegularExpressionSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, [html length])];
```

Or you can also use the [`replaceMatchesInString`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSRegularExpression_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009708-CH1-SW12) method of `NSRegularExpression`. Thus, assuming you have your html in a `NSMutableString *html`, you can:

```
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"<img[^>]*>"
                                                                       options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive
                                                                         error:nil];

[regex replaceMatchesInString:html
                      options:0
                        range:NSMakeRange(0, html.length)
                 withTemplate:@""];
```

I'd personally lean towards one of these options over the `stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfRegex` method of [`RegexKitLite`](http://regexkit.sourceforge.net/RegexKitLite/). There's no need to introduce a third-party library for something as simple as this unless there was some other compelling issue.

Answer (score 4):

Use a regular expression, find the matchs in your string and remove them !
Here is how

```
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"<img[^>]*>"
                                                                       options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive 
                                                                         error:nil];

NSMutableString* mutableString = [yourStringToStripFrom mutableCopy];
NSInteger offset = 0; // keeps track of range changes in the string due to replacements.
for (NSTextCheckingResult* result in [regex matchesInString:yourStringToStripFrom 
                                                    options:0 
                                                      range:NSMakeRange(0, [yourStringToStripFrom length])]) {

    NSRange resultRange = [result range];   
    resultRange.location += offset; 

    NSString* match = [regex replacementStringForResult:result 
                                               inString:mutableString 
                                                 offset:offset 
                                               template:@"$0"];

    // make the replacement
    [mutableString replaceCharactersInRange:resultRange withString:@""];

    // update the offset based on the replacement
    offset += ([match length] - resultRange.length);
}
```

Comment: I don't quite understand why you would need all this code in the for cycle. Could you explain the difference between your solution and mine? (Edited the question)

Answer (score 1):

You can use below function in Swift 4,5:

```
func filterImgTag(text: String) -> String{
    return text.replacingOccurrences(of: "<img[^>]*>", with: "", options: String.CompareOptions.regularExpression)
}
```

Hope it can help you all! comment below if it work for you. Thanks.