# Remove the HTML "img src" tag from a string

Tags: ios, regex, swift

I am trying to remove the image src tag from a string.

I have been following this past [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12496860/ios-strip-img-from-nsstring-a-html-string) on StackOverflow but it doesn't seem to be getting rid of the img src.

For example:

```
<img src="http://www.japanator.com/ul/33930-One Piece 696 cover 2.jpg
```

Into:

```
http://www.japanator.com/ul/33930-One Piece 696 cover 2.jpg
```

What my code outputs:

```
<img src="http://www.japanator.com/ul/33930-One Piece 696 cover 2.jpg
```

My code:

```
var images = item.summary.imageLinksFromHTMLString.first
var HTMLTagss: NSString = "<img[^>]*>" //regex to remove img tag
var stringWithoutImage: NSString = images!.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(HTMLTagss as String, withString: "", options: nil,range:nil)
println(stringWithoutImage)
```

Comment: Could you explain what "getting rid of the img src ... into ..." means? Did you provide the whole string? I suppose the HTML is valid and the closing `>` is on another line below. Please check and update the question.

Comment: I mean I just want the link so I can display the image. I updated the question to show the code output

Comment: Does `NSString *result = [images stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@".*<img\\b[^>]+\\bsrc=\"([^\"]*)\"[^>]*>.*" withString:@"$1" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch | NSRegularExpressionSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, [images length])];` work for you?

Comment: Hey did you ever get this working?