# How to fetch HTML image from JSON in Objective C?

Tags: ios

This is the JSON which I receive in message column with emoji:

```
<span class=\"atwho-inserted\"><img src=\"https://assets-cdn.github.com/images/icons/emoji/smile.png\" height=\"20\" width=\"20\"></span> <span class=\"atwho-inserted\"><img src=\"https://assets-cdn.github.com/images/icons/emoji/person_with_blond_hair.png\" height=\"20\" width=\"20\"></span>
```

Comment: see this link may be help with you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12496860/ios-strip-img-from-nsstring-a-html-string

Comment: Img Src will change often so how should i give it?

Comment: in HTML  tag , image url always start  like <img src=

Comment: @RomiPirisila FYI its not `JSON`, its pure HTML. You need to use `REGEX` to extract image.

Comment: @Dipen Panchasara Its pure Html wch i have to parse using JSON to my IOS APP.....In which no idea how to fetch html image src to IOS APP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
NSString *htmslStr=@"<span class=\"atwho-inserted\"><img src=\"https://assets-cdn.github.com/images/icons/emoji/smile.png\" height=\"20\" width=\"20\"></span> <span class=\"atwho-inserted\"><img src=\"https://assets-cdn.github.com/images/icons/emoji/person_with_blond_hair.png\" height=\"20\" width=\"20\"></span>";

NSError *error = NULL;
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"(<img\\s[\\s\\S]*?src\\s*?=\\s*?['\"](.*?)['\"][\\s\\S]*?>)+?"
                                                                       options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive
                                                                         error:&error];

[regex enumerateMatchesInString:htmslStr
                        options:0
                          range:NSMakeRange(0, [htmslStr length])
                     usingBlock:^(NSTextCheckingResult *result, NSMatchingFlags flags, BOOL *stop) {

                         NSString *img = [htmslStr substringWithRange:[result rangeAtIndex:2]];

                         NSURL *candidateURL = [NSURL URLWithString:img];

                         if (candidateURL && candidateURL.scheme && candidateURL.host)
                         {
                             NSLog(@"img src %@",img);
                         }


                     }];
```

the final Out put is

[image]

Comment: finally use this **img** string to where you need

Comment: in **htmslStr** --> pass your son string

Comment: Thank You @ Anbu.Karthik